# Behaviour of Inf in hist breaks, R

Tags: r

I would like to use Rs hist function to get bin counts. Since in don't know the lowest or highest value I used -Inf and Inf for the first and last break. But instead of counting -Inf to the first break, and the last break to Inf R puts all values in the first bin.

```
> hist(1:100, breaks=c(0, 50, 100), plot=F)$counts
[1] 50 50
> hist(1:100, breaks=c(-Inf, 50, 100), plot=F)$counts
[1] 100   0
> hist(1:100, breaks=c(0, 50, Inf), plot=F)$counts
[1] 100   0
> hist(1:100, breaks=c(-Inf, 50, Inf), plot=F)$counts
[1] 100   0
```

I would expect all four lines to give the same output but they don't. 
Is this expected behaviour? And are there any simple workarounds to the problem?

edit: I ended up using table and cut instead:

```
table(cut(1:100, breaks=c(-Inf, 50, Inf)))
```

Comment: What version of R are you using? I can't reproduce your results: I get 50 50 in all cases.

Comment: I'm using R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) maybe i should update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It causes issues for `hist` because the width of the blocks becomes infinite and by default `hist` considers the areas of the blocks in its computations:

> The default with non-equi-spaced breaks is to give a plot of area one,
>   in which the area of the rectangles is the fraction of the data points
>   falling in the cells.

You are best off using the single value version of the breaks argument: the number of breaks to use. By default it will choose sensible breaks for your data:

```
str(hist(1:100, breaks=3, plot=F))
List of 6
 $ breaks  : num [1:3] 0 50 100
 $ counts  : int [1:2] 50 50
 $ density : num [1:2] 0.01 0.01
 $ mids    : num [1:2] 25 75
 $ xname   : chr "1:100"
 $ equidist: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```